# How to see my visited question pages (URL) history?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks, accounts, history

Is there a way I can see my visited SOF questions (URL) history?

I visited some useful questions (and answers of course) last week, I had cleared the browser cache and history. Now, I'm not able to find the exact URL for those questions even from search engine results (I am not sure they updated their ranking algorithm!). So is there an option to find those URLs? If it's not there at present, it would be a useful feature to include. Any thoughts?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not track your history, no. That's what your browser history is for. If you cleared it, that's a pity, but not something Stack Overflow can or will help with.

Comment: Mark questions as favourite if they desire to be checked again by you. After that you can access them and also get notifications. StackOverflow does not track your history and such a thing could result with an huge unnecessary info. That's the responsibility of your web browser.

Comment: It is most definitely a useful future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do you know? Do you work for StackOverflow?

Comment: Your [upvote history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) might also be of use.

Comment: @BluE: no, if I worked for the company [you could see that on my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator?cb=1). I know because I've been a user of the site for over 10 years now. At the time I made that comment I hadn't yet seen the predictions feature data (it was rolled out in January 2015), and I'd not call that a question history either.

Comment: The reason I'd love to see a "5 or 10 recently view questions / answers" is so that I can go back and upvote good answers (or provide feedback on bad answers).  Oftentimes, when I'm looking for an answer and find something here, first thing I do is go and test it out.   Unfortunately, too often if the answer works, I've spent so much time already that I end up staying buried in code, and then shut down my browser at the end of the day. I'd love it if the next time I came back to SO, there was a message saying "Hey, did any of these questions you didn't upvote actually solve your problem?"

Answer (score 17):

I believe that both Martijn and animuson are incorrect in their assessment that viewed questions are not tracked. This information *is* available, in a round-about way. It's not a pretty UI, but the data is available.

It is available via your [personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data). If you haven't disabled the prediction data via that same link, the following will allow you to see what questions you've viewed.

Download the data from the above link. This is a `.json` file. You are looking for

```
['Data']['QuestionViews']
```

This contains a sizeable list, assuming you are active, of questions you've visited. This count is stored in `['Data']['TotalQuestionViews']`

You can view each item in  `['QuestionViews']` by creating a link that follows this format:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<ID>
```

Where `<ID>` is an element in the `['QuestionViews']` list. It *does* keep track of deleted questions, so if you are not a 10K user, you won't be able to see those particular questions.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome. How did you find out this? (which SE Employees couldn't)

Comment: It's not the [first time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287529/stack-exchange-should-review-and-document-their-data-retention-policies#comment933050_287529). ;) I just remembered that conversation. I found it originally just by looking through my prediction data.

Comment: @BhargavRao obviously 'cos it's Andy and he plays with this kind of stuff :) Although, I believe this is some quite nice "thinking outside of the box" stuff - the OP wanted a feature request of browsing history (probably displayed as part of the UI or easily accessible page) and I believe that's what animuson/Martijn would have been thinking along the lines of.

Comment: My "TotalQuestionViews" is 64192. I need to pump up those rookie numbers. Good work, Thanks for this :)

Comment: @Jon, looks like that. The prediction data is mentioned in the comments below the post which animuson has linked.

Comment: This is an interesting thing to look at but not super useful to most people. That list a) only records a question ID once and b) doesn't keep them in any meaningful order, so you wouldn't be able to track down any specific post based on how long ago you viewed it. It's quite literally *only* a list of question IDs. This also only works on Stack Overflow - no other site on the network can access data this way.

Comment: This did not work for me. "QuestionViews": null,

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange does not provide a history of questions you've visited, [nor is it interested in ever doing so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116315). Your browser provides plenty of tools for you to find such things and there's no point in Stack Exchange reinventing a wheel. If you've cleared your browser history, then your history is gone. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: The irony is that if you revisit a question that you were recently on, stackoverflow will let you know. But a history of questions is a useless feature. Sure!

Comment: this is a defeatist mindset. way to go stackoverflow for being stubborn over such a common feature. i'd rather have a list of recently visited posts than pour through ages of browser history

Comment: Disagree, even though there are existing tools allowing people to find recently visited pages, it is undeniable that having this as a dedicated feature in Stack Exchange would be useful.
My browser history will always contain much more than just Stack Exchange and, like you correctly pointed out, it is gone the minute it is cleared.